# How I can find out which postgresql I am connected into when behind a load balancer?

Tags: postgresql, master-slave-replication, load-balancing, load-testing

I have the following database replication setup:

[image]

As you can see I do a master-slave replication and I use aload balancer in order to connect into read-only replicas.

So I want to test this setup, hence I connect into my database into postgresql read-only replicas via Load Labalcer via `psql` command.

But how I can find out which replica I am connected into? I need that in order to perform a stress test.

Comment: `select inet_server_addr();` maybe? That returns the IP address of the database host.